# Index of same values in Tkinter Optionmenu widget

Tags: indexing, tkinter, optionmenu

I am trying to access the index of same values in optionmenu widget. In the following code, character "b" from the list returns index 1 no matter which of the two "b" characters I select. I need to differentiate both "b" characters based on their index position in the list i.e. selecting 1st "b" from the optionmenu widget should return index 1 while 2nd "b" should return index 2. Please tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

```py
from Tkinter import *
    
class GUI(Frame):
    
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("New window")
        self.master.geometry("300x200")
        self.grid()
            
        self.list1 = ["a", "b", "b"]
    
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.set("")
        self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.optionMenu = OptionMenu(self, self.var, *self.list1)
        self.optionMenu.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
        self.button = Button(self, text="Print", command=self.print_fun)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=2)
    
    def print_fun(self):
        print self.optionMenu["menu"].index(self.var.get())
    
obj = GUI()
    
obj.mainloop()
```

Comment: As in the anwser, you cant have same values in list1. You need to make them unique.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't how the option menu is designed to work. You'll have to create a custom option menu. An option menu isn't anything special, it's just a button and a menu, and a couple of functions to give it the behavior that it has.

From a usability perspective this is a very bad design, since the user has no way of knowing the difference between the first "b" choice and the second "b" choice. I hope one choice doesn't map to "deactivate the bomb" and the other is "explode the bomb".

Comment: While a do agree with this answer it omits a case, where having multiple same options in a menu is possible namely if for example we populate the menu using a configuration file (XAML for WPF, UI for Qt etc.). In testing this is a possibility and the fact that big name frameworks support it, does also prove that it has some application. I would say here it was more of a "I don't want to be bothered to implement this" case from the Tkinter developer(s). :D

Comment: @rbaleksandar: tkinter absolutely allows you to have multiple options on a menu with the same text if you're willing to deal with the usability aspects of it. The OptionMenu is just a quick-and-dirty solution for the 99+% of the time when all of the items are unique strings.